# Could not execute shell commands in sequence in Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I have to execute simple shell commands in ruby script one after other. Mys script does the following things in order: check if `ABC` services running, `if true then stop_services`; `delete directories`; `copy fresh directories from src to dest`. Below is the code:

```
def stop_ABC_services
     begin
       ABC_service_cnt = "ps -fu #{user} | grep ABC  | grep -v grep | wc -l"

       while exec "#{ABC_service_cnt } >& ABC.log".to_i > 0
           exec "sh stop_ABC.sh stop >>& ABC.log"
       end

     rescue => e
          puts "Error occured in stop_siebel_services - #{e}.".red
          Kernel.exit(false)
     end
end
```

But it is failing at the very first method `stop_ABC_services` by giving the following error: `Error occured in stop_ABC_services - can't convert false into String.
Cannot proceed further. Quitting...`

I am not able to figure out the solution for this. Appreciate the guidance to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Well, remove your error handling or add `puts e.backtrace` to it and post full error message please.

Comment: You probably meant `while exec("#{ABC_service_cnt } >& ABC.log").to_i > 0`

Comment: Note that `exec`, in accordance with the Unix system call of the same name, replaces the current process; it doesn't spawn a new one. This probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Instead of `exec` and the quotes, use the \`<command> \` syntax. It's that button above the ~. I think `exec` ends the process after it executes that command.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **use parentheses** (and don't use `exec`).

Longer answer: by not using parentheses you make ruby execute code in an order completely different from what you want. This

```
exec "#{ABC_service_cnt } >& ABC.log".to_i > 0
```

is executed in this sequence

```
"#{ABC_service_cnt } >& ABC.log".to_i # => 0
0 > 0 # => false
exec false # => TypeError: no implicit conversion of false into String
```

Should be this instead

```
while exec("#{ABC_service_cnt } >& ABC.log").to_i > 0
```

Also you might want not to use `exec` because it replaces the current process. Meaning, your `while` (and everything inside/after it) will not get a chance to run even once. Most likely you want `system()` call, which also handles zero/non-zero exit codes.

Comment: Thank you, adding parenthesis helped in fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that only executing sh

```
system("ps aux | grep ABC | grep -v grep  && stop_ABC.sh stop >>& ABC.log")
```

The meaning of that is.

&& will run `stop_ABC.sh stop >>& ABC.log` if `ps aux | grep ABC | grep -v grep`

you could find more [info here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37069/what-is-the-difference-between-and-when-chaining-commands)

Answer (score 0):

```
def stop_ABC_services
 begin
   ABC_service_cnt = "ps -fu #{user} | grep ABC  | grep -v grep | wc -l"

   while exec("#{ABC_service_cnt } >& ABC.log").to_i > 0
       exec "sh stop_ABC.sh stop >>& ABC.log"
   end

 rescue => e
      puts "Error occured in stop_ABC_services - #{e}.".red
      Kernel.exit(false)
 end
end
```